# How can I add a shorthand if statement in blade, laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

How can I add a shorthand if statement in blade, laravel, that adds a class to my bootstrap form input of 'alert-danger', that gives it a red border/outline when doing form validation? Basically I want to check if there is a form error and if there is I want the input to have a red outline.

This is what I have but the class of 'alert-danger' is not being applied:

```
<div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
                {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control'], $errors->first('email') ? ['class'=>'alert-danger'] : '') !!}
</div>
```

Please keep in mind I'm fairly new to Laravel and Blade.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
{!! Form::email('email', null, ['class'=> $errors->first('email') ? 'alert-danger form-control' : 'form-control']) !!}
```